# FontLab - OpenType feature for changing numbers to roman notation

Tags: opentype

I would like to use an opentype feature in my font, I'm creating in FontLab, that would transform all the numbers to roman notation. This is the OpeType Feature code I'm using:

```
feature liga{
  sub @arabic by @roman1;
  sub @roman1' @roman1 by @roman2;
  sub @roman2' @roman2 by @roman3;
  sub @roman3' @roman3 by @roman4;
} liga;
```

Classes 'arabic' and 'roman1-4' all contain numbers from 0 to 9, where roman1 contains: [empty symbol], I, II... IX, roman2: [empty smbol], X, XX... XC, etc.

Numbers up to 99 are working as they should, but above 100 only roman2 glyphs are being repeated, so instead 111 being 'CXI', I get 'XXI'. I'm not sure what the right syntax for opentype features should look like and where exactly is the problem.

Comment: OpenType has no associated programming language, so: what application or language is the code you're showing for? And as a question about coding opentype features in some specific application,asking this on a forum dedicated to OpenType like [typedrawers.com](http://typedrawers.com) feels far more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This example I used was from FontLab feature coding. I'm new to font creation and thus I didn't knew any other site to ask that question on other than StackOverflow.

Comment: remember that your question is going to be found by people far in the future long after you even remember ever asking this, so please update your question so that it simply contains that information: update the text to mention fontlab (and the version) so that details that should be in the question can be found there, not in comments or in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have solved my problem already. The reason why it wasn't working was that all the rules were run in a single pass of the word as one rule instead of them being run one after another through whole word. This is the correct solution:

```
feature liga{
   lookup rOne {
      sub @arabic by @roman1;
   } rOne;
   lookup rTwo {
      sub @roman1' @roman1 by @roman2;
   } rTwo;
   lookup rThree {
      sub @roman2' @roman2 by @roman3;
   } rThree;
   lookup rFour {
      sub @roman3' @roman3 by @roman4;
   } rFour;
} liga;
```

P.S.: To clarify, this code is for FontLab's OpenType features coding